# Kotlin Jackson serialization issue

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, jackson, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm testing out **PubSub** message sending which has a bean called **PubSubTemplate** which allows to send messages towards **PubSub** and I want to send **raw JSON**, but I've noticed that other application which consumes **PubSub** message fails to deserialise it. The issue is when **JacksonPubSubMessageConverter** converts payload to **PubSubMessage** it uses `ByteString.copyFrom(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(payload)`) and it double encodes my payload so when reading happens actual json looks like this: `\"{ \\\"value\\\": 42 }\"`

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
  objectMapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())

  val payload = "{ \"value\": 42 }"

  val payloadEncoded = ByteString.copyFrom(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(payload))
  val readValue = objectMapper.readerFor(TestClass::class.java).readValue<TestClass>(payloadEncoded.toByteArray())
  println(readValue)
}

data class TestClass(var value: Int)
```

How I should create my payload so it would correctly encode it and would be able to deserialize into an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes` converts its argument to JSON. Since your `payload` string is *already* JSON, you can skip the call to `objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes` and just call `ByteString.copyFrom(payload.toByteArray())`.